# Configuracion del web.Config <system.serviceModel>

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, xml, webservice

Buenas noches,

Como puedo configurar el "system.serviceModel" en el Web.Config, esque me esta dando el siguiente error la aplicacion:

> No se encontró el elemento de extremo predeterminado que hace referencia al contrato 'VirusWS.scanFile' en la sección de configuración de cliente de ServiceModel. La razón puede ser que no se encontró ningún archivo de configuración para la aplicación o que no se encontró ningún elemento de extremo correspondiente a este contrato en el elemento de cliente.

Y buscando en Internet me dice que agregar manualmente los endpoint, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Éste es el .WSDL:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="scanFile"
    targetNamespace="http://algo.com/algo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="http://algo.com/algo"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <message name="scanRequest">
    <part name="file" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
  </message>
  <message name="scanResponse">
    <part name="success" type="xsd:string"/>
  </message>

  <portType name="scanFile">
    <operation name="scan">
      <input message="tns:scanRequest" name="scanRequest"/>
      <output message="tns:scanResponse" name="scanResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>

  <binding name="scanFileBinding" type="tns:scanFile">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name="scan">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <input name="scanRequest">
        <mime:multipartRelated>
          <mime:part name="bodyPart">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </mime:part>
          <mime:part name="fileToScan">
            <mime:content part="file"/>
          </mime:part>
        </mime:multipartRelated>
      </input>
      <output name="scanResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>

  <service name="scanFileService">
    <port binding="tns:scanFileBinding" name="scanFilePort">
      <soap:address location="https://111.11.111.11:111"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Agrego mi web.config

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Servicio Virus Scan-20170921114749.mdf&quot;;Initial Catalog=&quot;aspnet-Servicio Virus Scan-20170921114749&quot;;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
       ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
       ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
         ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Cuando pruebo el servicio con el SOAP UI me aparece asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, has probado en agregar una Service Reference en tu proyecto al servicio scanFileService, en este caso a tu ruta donde tienes el archivo WSDL. Automáticamente te generaría la entrada en el web.config.

Comment: Ese es el problema, que no lo hace.

Comment: Y cuando llega a la linea donde instancio el servicio me genera la exception que arriba menciono,  estoy instanciando asi el servicio: scanWS.scanFileClient prueba = new scanWS.scanFileClient();

Comment: Hola, prueba a crearte un proyecto de app console nuevo y realiza los pasos de mi respuesta, debería de generarte las entradas en el app.config y luego las trasladas a tu proyecto actual. Espero explicarme. Puede que tengas algún problema con tu VS.

Comment: Vale, ya lo hago, lo estoy haciendo en el VS 2013 de un servidor, voy a hacerlo en mi vS 2015 local y te aviso, gracias .

Comment: Te recomiendo ejecutes el VS como Administrador

Comment: Nada, no lo hace, ejecute como administrador y nada.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65987/discussion-between-sergio-parra-guerra-and-andres-felipe).

Answer (score 0):

1. Pulsa botón derecho del ratón en el archivo de tu proyecto en la Explorador de Soluciones.
2. "Add Service Reference"
3. En la caja de texto Address selecciona la ruta física donde tienes el archivo .WSDL.
4. Pulsar en Go.

PD: tengo el Visual Studio en inglés por lo que en español sería directo también.

Comment: @SergiParraGuerra Hola, gracias, gracias por el interes de ayudar, asi como me lo indicas lo e estado haciendo, pero me da el error que arriba indico, el error se produce exactamente en la instancia del servicio, aqui: scanWS.scanFileClient prueba = new scanWS.scanFileClient();

Comment: Hola, genera tu cliente proxy como `Web Reference` en vez de `Service Reference`.

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra me sirvio para solucionar el mismo problema, gracias crack